# How do I close the loop?

Tags: python, while-loop

I am given an array of n numbers [a0,a1, a2, …, an-1] and I am supposed to write a function named sumOfThree that takes in the array and a number K as the only 2 arguments and outputs the number of unique unordered triplets in the array that sum to K. This is my code:

```
def sumOfArray(arr,K):
    arr.sort()
    
    s=set()
    for i in range(len(arr)-2):
        j=i+1
        k=len(arr)-1
        while j<k:
            
            if arr[i]+arr[j]+arr[k]==K:
                s.add((arr[i],arr[j],arr[k]))
            elif arr[i]+arr[j]+arr[k]<K:
                j+=1
            else:
                k-=1        
        
    return len(s)
```

However I am unable to find the answer. Any help please?

Comment: You're getting stuck in your `if` statement – if the if statement is true, neither j nor k gets updated, and the while loop continues forever

Comment: Also, if you're interested check out the classic `three-sum` problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as MZ mentioned,

when arr[i]+arr[j]+arr[k]==K, the i,j,k never changed.

However, if you just add a single break as cewaphi mentioned, the while loop will stop at first match for every i loop, instead of walking through all the combinations.

Here is another way to solve the problem:

```
def sumOfArray(arr, K):
     arr.sort()
     s = set()
     count = 0
     for i in range(len(arr) - 2):
          for j in range(i+1,len(arr)-1):
               for k in range(j+1,len(arr)):
                    if arr[i] + arr[j] + arr[k] == K:
                         s.add((arr[i], arr[j], arr[k]))
     print('Done')
     length = print('length: ' + str(len(s)))
     return length
```

Answer (score 0):

As MZ stated, you are stuck in your if condition.

Either increment j or decrement k so that the condition j < k is met.
**Or** if you are done with increment i and want to continue with i+1, simply add a `break`:

```
        if arr[i]+arr[j]+arr[k]==K:
            s.add((arr[i],arr[j],arr[k]))
            break
```

Comment: Solved! Thank you!

Comment: No problem. If your problem is solved, can you accept the answer to close the question?